# my domain name on the azure microsoft

Tags: azure, dns, seo

I opened a "shared" web site on azure microsoft. my domain name is "mydn.azurewebsites.net" ,I purchased a domain name "mydomain.co.il" and did the following from https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/ to make my domain name work. 
my dns provider told me to add "url forwarding " to "mydn.azurewebsites.net" . 
my Q is. will it cause problems with SEO ? google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same as you and have not had any problems.

My DNS server is set up with a CNAME entry that points to mydomain.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: 10x, how do you send mails ? sendgrid ?

Comment: I've actually gone over to the competition on that one and use Amazon's mail service (SES)

Comment: can I use my gmail on this service ?